# JavaScript: What does "functions are executable" mean?

Tags: javascript, algorithm

I'm currently reading John Resig JavaScript Ninja book.
There he writes that functions have the "super power" of being executable.

I don't understand what "being executable" means.

Does it mean that the JavaScript interpreter takes the code which exists as a string and translates it into machine code? Which is then executed by the CPU?
But in case of that: Other data are also processed by the CPU. Where is the differentiation?

Can someone explain the term "executable" in a way which is understandable for a non computer-science graduate?

Comment: Strings are executable too, if you pass them to eval

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it means that a function is a set of instructions that the cpu can execute. compared to other programing constructs like variables and objects, that simply hold data, this is kind of special..

specialy in languages like javascript where functions are objects. the "being executable" is preatty special.

so imageine like this. `a` is variable object, that means it holds **data**

```
 a = 10
```

the computer knows that `a` has the value `10`, but it does not know what it means, or what to do with it.
an function object on the other hand holds **instructions**

```
function a(){do{...}while(b=10)}
```

this menas the computer knows what to do with. it can take the instructions of `a` and execute them one by one..

Comment: Yeah. Makes sense. Thanks a lot.

Comment: One can say that a function contains instructions for the CPU.

Comment: yes.. of course al of this depends on the actual implementation of the language and the compiler/interpreter.. but in a conceptual sense a function is a set of executable instructions..

Answer (score 3):

I presume a simpler interpretation: it means a function (as a special object) can be called, while an object in general may not be.

```
var foo = function() {};
foo(); // call or "execute" it

var bar = {};
bar(); // TypeError: bar is not a function
```

From a POV of hardware and OS there are distinction of (non-executable) data and executable instructions, but high level languages like javascript are designed to free people from such detail.